# Random event system in C# . How to do it?

Tags: c#, function, actionscript-3, random

I am just a beginner in the world of programming, thus I have a simple question. Is it possible to randomly execute functions? If so, how would you do it? It is just a curiosity based on a thread I've read in another forum. Basically, the discussion was on how to generate random events for a game, and they commented about a "hack" used in some languages (especially AS3). The hack is to treat functions as variables. Example:

```
//Make an array of the functions
public function makeEarthquake():void{}
public function causePlague():void{}
public function spaceZombieAttack():void{}

//select at random
var selection:uint = Math.random() * eventArrray.length;
//Call it
eventArray[selection]();
```

I hope this is clear. I will be happy with any answer that can explain how to randomly call methods. Thank you.

EDIT: Thank you guys, all the answers were helpful!!!

Comment: Techically, you _could_ have a list of delegates with references to several methods, randomly pick an item from the list and invoke the delegate (aka execute the method). So yes, in theory it's possible, but in practice it sounds really dangerous...

Comment: You could have `List<Func>` and use the same logic you have in your question.

Comment: in C# it's not a hack.. just create a List of delegates (you need of course the same signature for all the events) and pick from a random index

Comment: It's not a hack in AS3, either. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible. A direct way is to have a list or array of delegates:

In C# it looks like this: (In a basic console app)

```
class Program
{
    // Create the functions:
    static void Beep()
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }

    static void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }

    // Create the function delegate:
    private delegate void RandomFunction();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a list of these delegates:
        List<RandomFunction> functions = new List<RandomFunction>();

        // Add the functions to the list:
        functions.Add(Beep);
        functions.Add(SayHello);

        // Make our randomizer:
        Random rand = new Random();

        // Call one:
        functions[rand.Next(0, 2)](); // Random number either 0 or 1

        // This is just here to stop the program
        // from closing straight away should it say "Hello"
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Getting these functions to have varying numbers of parameters takes a bit more effort, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `List<Action>` and randomly select from it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

        actions.Add(() => Program.MakeEarthquake());
        actions.Add(() => Program.CausePlague());
        actions.Add(() => Program.SpaceZombieAttack());

        Random random = new Random();

        int selectedAction = random.Next(0, actions.Count());

        actions[selectedAction].Invoke();
    }

    static void MakeEarthquake()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Earthquake");
    }

    static void CausePlague()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Plague");
    }

    static void SpaceZombieAttack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Zombie attack");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create list of actions then choosing one the items inside the list randomly like below code

```
    List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
    actions.Add(() => makeEarthquake());
    actions.Add(() => causePlague());
    actions.Add(() => spaceZombieAttack());
    var random=new Random();
    int rndNumber = random.Next(actions.Count);
    actions[rndNumber].Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pick a random number like usual, then use that number within a common function which in turn calls a function based on what you got?

```
public void DoRandomThing()
{
    switch(new Random().Next(1,4))
    {
        case 1:
            makeEarthquake();
            break;
        case 2:
            causePlague();
            break;
        case 3:
            spaceZombieAttack();
            break;
    }
}
```